# Getting stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

When I'm running this program for class, I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop whenever I enter a '|' character to end the while loop. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

This problem is found on page 126 of Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Programming book, but as a quick rundown, I'm just supposed to find the largest and smallest numbers that are typed in the by the user and return info on it. Typing in '|' is supposed to exit the loop so that I can get down to the part where it gives information about all the numbers inputted, but whenever I type that character (or any character that's not a number), it creates an infinite loop.

Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> nums;

    while (true)
    {
        double current_num;
        cout << "enter a double \n";
        cin >> current_num;
        if (current_num == '|')
            break;
        nums.push_back(current_num);
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        cout << nums[nums.size()-1] << " is the largest so far.\n";
        cout << nums[0] << " is the smallest so far.\n";
    }
    cout << nums[nums.size()-1] << " is the largest number.\n";
    cout << nums[0] << " is the smallest number.\n";
    cout << "Number of values entered: " << nums.size() << '\n';
    double sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k<nums.size(); ++k)
        sum += nums[0];
    cout << "Sum of all values: " << sum << '\n';
    for (int j=0; j<nums.size(); ++j)
        cout << nums[j] << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

I was using VS13 in class and I wasn't having this problem, but now I'm coding in notepad++ and using PuTTY to compile at home (although I doubt this has anything to do with it).

Comment: `'|'` is not a `double`, is it?

Comment: Why are you storing the numbers in an array and sorting them? Just keep running values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing a character with a `double` here :

```
if (current_num == '|')
```

And this comparison will never do what you want it to do.

Read a character first, compare it with `'|'`, then do a double conversion if necessary.

---

**Note:**

For your record the ASCII value of `'|'` is 124, so if you enter 124 your loop will end...

Comment: The problem is not (only) the comparison but the string value inserted into the double. The comparison doesn't create the infinite loop. the insertion does.

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing number with a character.

```
if (current_num == '|')
```

`current_num` contains the number in type double that you are trying to compare with a char which is `'|'`

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It's correct. It was given roughly at the same time as quantdev's answer and it's roughly the same, yet quantdev's is +4 now, and this one is -1.

Comment: I had some mistakes and I rectified them :)

Comment: may by the original was not that precise, but it already was correct. Even if someone thought that it didn't deserve an upvote, I don't see any reason anyone would downvote it. That's why I'm surprised. Nice nickname, btw :)

Comment: @FreeNickname thanks for being so pedantic ;) ya I know it is clooest name ever lol ;)

Comment: Didn't downvote, but FWIW this is kind of "part 2" of the problem though... "part 1" is not reading from `std::cin` into an appropriate type, or choosing a sentinel like 0 or -1 instead of `'|'`.

Comment: @TonyD, thanks for the opinion, you have a point. But it's still strange, because almost the same answer nearby (which also doesn't mention `std::cin`, by the way) has a much higher score. Of course, I don't blame quantdev for having a higher score, I'm just surprised.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to insert a non number into a double.
I thing that in your case you should read the input into a string/char and parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here:

```
if(current_num == '|'){
}
```

Instead read in a `std::string` and parse it to a double.

So the modified snippet will look something like this:

```
while (true)
    {
        string strNum;
        double current_num;
        cout << "enter a double \n";
        cin >> strNum;
        if (strNum == "|")
            break;
        istringstream strm(strNum);
        strm >> current_num;
        nums.push_back(current_num);
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        cout << nums[nums.size()-1] << " is the largest so far.\n";
        cout << nums[0] << " is the smallest so far.\n";
    }
```